# What is the difference by adding "as"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

The test does not **mean as much** to her.

The test does not **mean much** to her

Any changes in meaning?

Comment: What do you think the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

*As X* is a comparative structure.

Whenever you see *as X*, there's another *Y* that the X is being compared to, even if it's not expressed.

> The test does not mean as much to her.

So the test doesn't mean as much to her *as something else*, *like something else*, or *than something else*.  We'd have to have more of the conversation to know.

It's possible the test means a lot to her, but it means a lot more to someone else.

> The test does not mean much to her.

There is no comparison here.  We're just saying the amount of meaning the test has for her is low.

Answer (score 0):

Out of context

> The test does not mean as much to her.

simply is wrong.  Context could supply something to compare to, but as it stands, it's comparing to nothingness.

> The test does not mean much to her

This works because it's absolute.

Answer (score -2):

Well, let me show how you *can* use

*The test does not mean as much to her. [ungrammatical]

If we add a clause also beginning with "as" as a conjunction, such as "as it does to other students" or "as going out and partying", then we have viable sentences:

- The test does not mean as much to her as it does to other students.
- The test does not mean as much to her as [does] going out and
  partying.

The use of the second "does" in the second example is correct, but people, more commonly American English speakers rather than British English speakers, frequently drop that "does."